# Slider takes multiple clicks to scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm having some trouble with [BJQS](http://basic-slider.com/) slider.  It seems like the initialization is not happening properly.  It takes a few clicks before the slider begins to scroll.  Can anyone identify what I am doing wrong? Or is this a bug in the plugin?

**HTML**

```
<div id="dialog">
    <ul class="bjqs">
        <li class="slide">One</li>
        <li class="slide">Two</li>
        <li class="slide">Three</li>
        <li class="slide">Four</li>
        <li class="slide">Five</li>
        <li class="slide">Six</li>
        <li class="slide">Seven</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
$(function(){    
$('#dialog').bjqs({
        'showmarkers':false,
        'responsive':true,
        'randomstart':true,
        'automatic':false
});
});
```

Here is the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XJH9X/2/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue was that all your slides were visible when the slider was initialized.

See updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/XJH9X/4/

This meant that it looked like it took several clicks to get started, but what happened was that one of the slides was displaying over the others.

Quick fix - just set slides to hidden by default, the slider will take care of displaying the correct one:

```
.slide{
    background:#ccc;
    height:300px;
    width:400px;
    display: none;
}
```